# Can I use NuGet or Chocolatey to provide automatic updates for my application?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, auto-update, chocolatey

Is there any auto update tool or component for .Net which uses NuGet or Chocolatey.

The idea is to create a own repository with different versions in our own server (like NuGet Repositories) and use NuGet or Chocolatey for software updates. It should also support running some SQL queries before updating or after updating ? Not only SQL but could be any other task like updating registry.

Comment: Chocolatey supports running SQL, updating the registry or pretty much anything you can do in PowerShell. There is the chocolatey.lib, which you can get off of the NuGet gallery at https://nuget.org/packages/chocolatey.lib

Answer (score 0):

Chocolatey has a built-in mechanism for updating packages. So as long as you update the version number and configure chocolatey to look at your NuGet repository, you can simply update your package with:

`choco update PackageName`